# CMake can't find python3

Tags: path, clion, pythoninterpreter

In my CMake I have:

```
find_package(PythonInterp 3.6 REQUIRED)
```

This works fine when I execute cmake ., because I have python3.6 in /opt/local/bin. However, when CLion executes the same cmake, it is unable to find it. How can I make it aware?

I tried adding /opt/local/bin to PATH and adding a python interpreter setting, but nether worked for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. It is possible to add env variables to cmake execution: look for `env` in here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html

Knowing this it was easy to add it in clion: Settings/Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake -> CMake Options

and add into that field `env PATH=${PATH}:/opt/local/bin`.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by adding an extra parameter to cmake which is: Python3_EXECUTABLE

> cmake -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/bin/python3 ..

Comment: Yup, that solved it for me too, -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is temporarily set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` with `/usr/local` where python is installed in some platforms (happens in macOS).

```
+            set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_bak ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
+            set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local")
             find_package(PythonInterp)
+            set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_bak})
```